# images doesn't appear after the npm run build with react

Tags: reactjs

I built a react app. Everything was fine, no errors, and after `npm run build` the images aren't found. [here is an example of an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otcdI.png)
[and here is how I access it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZLTj.png),
but in the browser it doesn't recognize them as images [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ6XH.png).
The only one that it recognizes is the banner which is the only one that I use as a background image
[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yydSd.png)

Here are the folders normally it should put the apple-images in media but it extracts only the banner.

I already verified every single path.

here are some code snippets

````
export const storeData = [
  {
    type: "Mac",
    product: [

      {
        name: "MacBook Air avec puce M1",
        prix: 1199,
        screen: " 13.3 pouces",
        puce: "Puce Apple M1",
        RAM: "8 Go ou 16 Go de mémoire unifiée",
        stockage: "256 Go à 2 To de stockage",
        autonomie: "jusqu'à 18 heures d'autonomie",

        gadgets: "Touch ID, Touch bar",
        options: {
          stockage: {
            taille1: { taille: "256 Go", prix: 0 },
            taille2: { taille: "512 Go", prix: 230 },
            taille3: { taille: "1 To", prix: 460 },
            taille4: { taille: "2 To", prix: 920 },
          },
          RAM: {
            taille1: { taille: "8 Go", prix: 0 },
            taille2: { taille: "16 Go", prix: 230 },
          },
        },
        dimensions: {
          Hauteur: "0.41 à 1.61 cm",
          Largeur: "30.41cm",
          Profondeur: "21.24cm",
          Poids: "1.29 kg",
        },
        exploitation: "macOS",
        productImage: "./apple-images/shop-items/mac-book-air.jpg",
      },
      {
        name: 'MacBook Pro 13"',
        prix: 1599,
        screen: " 13.3 pouces",
        puce: "Puce Apple M2",
        RAM: "8 Go à 24 Go de mémoire unifiée",
        stockage: "256 Go à 2 To de stockage",
        autonomie: "jusqu'à 20 heures d'autonomie",
        gadgets: "Touch ID , Touch Bar",
        options: {
          stockage: {
            taille1: { taille: "256 Go", prix: 0 },
            taille2: { taille: "512 Go", prix: 230 },
            taille3: { taille: "1 To", prix: 460 },
            taille4: { taille: "2 To", prix: 920 },
          },
          RAM: {
            taille1: { taille: "8 Go", prix: 0 },
            taille2: { taille: "16 Go", prix: 230 },
          },
        },
        dimensions: {
          Hauteur: "1.56cm",
          Largeur: "30.41cm",
          Profondeur: "21.24cm",
          Poids: "1.4 kg",
        },
        exploitation: "macOS",

        productImage: "./apple-images/shop-items/macbookPro.png",
      },
    ],
    frontImage: "./apple-images/store-image/mac.png",},}]`
```

so that's the js object it's called storeData

and here is how I use it 

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import StoreContext from "./storeContext";
    import { storeData } from "./StoreData.js";
    import BuyModal from "./BuyModal.jsx";
    import Cart from "./Cart.jsx";
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";


 export function StoreComponent({ Data }) {

   
let prevType = null;
   const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState(null);
   const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState([]);
   const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState([]);
   const [ShowModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const [showBlurBackground, setShowBlurBackground] =useState(false);
  const [newConfig, setNewConfig] = useState({});
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    // Générer un nouvel ID unique

    const newId = uuidv4();

    // Ajouter le nouvel élément au tableau cartItems avec l'ID 

unique
    setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...newConfig, id: newId }]);


    console.log(cartItems);
  };

  const handleClick = (name) => {
    setShowModal(true);
    setShowBlurBackground(true);
    const product = storeData
      .filter((item) => item.product.find((p) => p.name === name))
      .flatMap((item) => item.product)
      .find((p) => p.name === name);
    const serializedObject = JSON.stringify(product);
    setSelectedItem(serializedObject);
  };

  const handleClickCart = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsClicked(false);
    setShowModal(false);
    setShowBlurBackground(false);
  };

  const onStoreSelectorClick = (type) => {
    // Mettre à jour le type de produit sélectionné
    setSelectedType(type);

    // Filtrer les produits correspondants au type sélectionné
    const products = storeData
      .filter((item) => item.type === type)
      .flatMap((item) => item.product);
    setSelectedProducts(products);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Appeler la fonction onStoreSelectorClick avec la valeur "Mac" lors du chargement initial de la page
    onStoreSelectorClick("Mac");
  }, []); // [] en tant que 2ème argument pour que la fonction ne soit appelée qu'une seule fois au chargement initial de la page

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{ newConfig, setNewConfig }}>
      <div>
        <div
          className={`StoreNav ${
            showBlurBackground ? "blurred-background" : ""
          }`}
        >
          {storeData &&
            storeData.map((item, index) => {
              if (item.type !== prevType) {
                prevType = item.type;
                return (
                  <div
                    className={`StoreSelector ${
                      selectedType === item.type ? "active" : ""
                    }`}
                    type={item.type}
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => onStoreSelectorClick(item.type)}
                  >
                    <img className="categorie" src={item.frontImage} alt="" />
                    <p>{item.type}</p>
                  </div>
                );
              }
              return null;
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="ItemsWrap">
          {selectedProducts.map((product, index) => (
            <div
              className={`item ${
                showBlurBackground ? "blurred-background" : ""
              }`}
              key={index}
            >
              <h1>{product.name}</h1>
              <div className="images">
                <img className="itemImg" src={product.productImage} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="text">
                <p>A partir de {product.prix}€</p>
                <button
                  className="Buy"
                  onClick={() => handleClick(product.name)}
                >
                  Acheter
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
          {ShowModal && (
            <BuyModal
              products={selectedItem}
              onClose={handleClose}
              onAdd={handleAddToCart}
            />
          )}
          <Cart
            onClose={handleClose}
            onOpen={handleClickCart}
            isClicked={isClicked}
            Items={cartItems}
            setCartItems={setCartItems}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
}
```
````

Comment: The thing is react follows a path for the root, you will have to configure them, As you can see the error is 404 meaning the react server after build is not able to find the assets folder, Can you check the paths, and make it point to the assets folder ? Also this needs some more info, Kindly upload code snippets instead of images

Answer (score 0):

i used import from instead of trying to use directly the js object